# Can I print only some functions with minted?

Tags: minted

I often have to print Source Code, but quite often only some parts of a project. Now I got a task to improve two functions and I have to print out what I change. I use minted for printing source code.

How can I tell minted to print only a given function?

Something like:

```
\inputminted[functions=helloWorld,functions=abc,
                fontsize=\footnotesize, tabsize=4]{c}{/home/moose/Desktop/RO/blatt02.c}
```

If this is not possible, I'd also accept if I could tell minted to print some given lines, e.g.:

```
\inputminted[from=12, to=50,
                fontsize=\footnotesize, tabsize=4]{c}{/home/moose/Desktop/RO/blatt02.c}
```

This would not be as good as the functions, but it would be ok.

Comment: You should consider using the [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) that allows this kind of printing requirements.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[image: Method 1]

<sup>I did, egreg! I did it by myself! Best day ever! Well, technically it's night. Anyway. `:)`</sup>

May Konrad Rudolph have mercy on me. `:)` The following code is a dirty, dirty hack. But we do love dirty code, don't we?

First things first. This trick relies on the powerful `awk`. We can print ranges from a document by using the format `'NR==x,NR==y'`, where `x` means "the current line is the `x`<sup>th</sup> line" and `y` means "the current line is the `y`<sup>th</sup> line". So `awk` will print the interval between them.

We can pipe the `awk` output to `pygmentize`, which is used by `minted`. Then I added two options to `minted`:

- `linestart`: the first line to be printed.
- `lineend`: the last line to be printed.

First, let's consider the following `helloworld.c` sample code (lines added for our convenience):

```c
1. #include <stdio.h>
2. 
3. int main(void) {
4.     printf("Hello world\n");
5.     return 0;
6. }
```

Now the `.tex` code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\makeatletter
\minted@define@opt{linestart}{NR==#1}
\minted@define@opt{lineend}{NR==#1}
\renewcommand\minted@pygmentize[2][\jobname.pyg]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@opt@linestart}{}}{\def\minted@awk{}}{\def\minted@awk{awk '\minted@opt{linestart},\minted@opt{lineend}' #1 |}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@opt@linestart}{}}{\def\minted@fromsource{#1}}{\def\minted@fromsource{}}
\def\minted@cmd{\minted@awk pygmentize -l #2 -f latex -F tokenmerge
\minted@opt{gobble} \minted@opt{texcl} \minted@opt{mathescape}
\minted@opt{startinline} \minted@opt{funcnamehighlighting}
\minted@opt{linenos} -P "verboptions=\minted@opt{extra}"
-o \jobname.out.pyg \minted@fromsource}
\immediate\write18{\minted@cmd}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@opt@bgcolor}{}}
{}
{\begin{minted@colorbg}{\minted@opt@bgcolor}}
\input{\jobname.out.pyg}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@opt@bgcolor}{}}
{}
{\end{minted@colorbg}}
\DeleteFile{\jobname.out.pyg}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\inputminted[linestart=3,lineend=5]{c}{helloworld.c}
\end{document}
```

After running it (of course, with `--shell-escape` enabled), this is our output:

[image: The output]

There we go, `minted` with line ranges. `:)`

[image: Method 2]

**Edit:** Back to the crafting table. `:)`

My good friend [Marco Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5239) pointed out an out-of-the-box solution which is way more appropriate for this case: using `firstline` and `lastline` options from `fancyvrb/minted` themselves. It does exactly what I did in the previous attempt, but without all the dangerous bends I went through:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\inputminted[firstline=3,lastline=5]{c}{helloworld.c}
\end{document}
```

And we shall obtain the very same result. `:)`

[image: Method 3]

**Edit:** For the sake of completeness, I decided to try again and print the function scope based on its full qualified name. Here it goes. `:)`

The following `awk` code is taken from [How to extract a C function definition from a C source file](http://www.issociate.de/board/post/480405/How_to_extract_a_C_function_definition_from_a_C_source_file.html). According to the author, "the following assumes balanced braces, and that the closing `}` for a function
is the last character in its line." I modified it slightly in order to set the function name. The original code had the function to extract hardcoded.

```
function match_braces() {
s=$0
# how to abuse gsub
op=gsub(/{/,"",s);
cl=gsub(/}/,"",s);
if (op || cl) f=1;
return (op-cl);
}

match($0, v) {ok=1}
ok {n+=match_braces(); print; if ((n==0)&&(f==1)) exit}
```

I saved it as `extract.awk` and put it in the same directory of my `.tex` file. It would be wiser to create an alias or even a shell script to wrap the call to this code and export it to the path. I'm taking the easier route, for obvious reasons. `:)`

Lets use another `helloworld.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void sayHello() {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}

void sayGoodBye() {
    printf("Goodbye world!\n");
}

int main(void) {
    sayHello();
    sayGoodBye();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, our `.tex` code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\minted@define@opt{function}{#1}
\renewcommand\minted@pygmentize[2][\jobname.pyg]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@opt@function}{}}{\def\minted@awk{}}{\def\minted@awk{awk -vv="\minted@opt@function" -f extract.awk #1 |}}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@opt@function}{}}{\def\minted@fromsource{#1}}{\def\minted@fromsource{}}
\def\minted@cmd{\minted@awk pygmentize -l #2 -f latex -F tokenmerge
\minted@opt{gobble} \minted@opt{texcl} \minted@opt{mathescape}
\minted@opt{startinline} \minted@opt{funcnamehighlighting}
\minted@opt{linenos} -P "verboptions=\minted@opt{extra}"
-o \jobname.out.pyg \minted@fromsource}
\immediate\write18{\minted@cmd}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@opt@bgcolor}{}}
{}
{\begin{minted@colorbg}{\minted@opt@bgcolor}}
\input{\jobname.out.pyg}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@opt@bgcolor}{}}
{}
{\end{minted@colorbg}}
\DeleteFile{\jobname.out.pyg}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\inputminted[function={int main}]{c}{helloworld.c}

\lipsum[1]

\inputminted[function={void sayHello}]{c}{helloworld.c}

\lipsum[1]

\inputminted[function={void sayGoodBye}]{c}{helloworld.c}

\end{document}
```

Our new output:

[image: Output 5]

As Konrad mentioned in the comments, this trick is not portable, since it works only with a few range of languages and it relies on certain code standards. Nonetheless, it's a neat feature. `:)`

Comment: Mercy? This is awesome! Now, if only I had time to integrate it in the package … but maybe soon! **EDIT** Actually, this is probably not portable enough, meaning it only works on C and only on simple functions … :(

Comment: @Konrad: Thanks for the kind words. `:)` `awk` is very powerful with getting the line ranges for any file, but I can't think of a Windows counterpart command. We can use it with other languages too, not only C: `awk` just reads the text file and outputs the lines in the selected range, nothing more. `:)` I could only come up with this solution thanks to the `minted` manual, it's extremely well commented. Thanks a lot for this great package! `:)`

Comment: I know what `awk` does. I misread your answer (and didn’t look at the source) as parsing out the relevant function *by name* and that’s not trivial, and not generally feasible with `awk`. But since you only use lines, that’s not a problem, true. Truth to be told, there should be a TeX-only solution for this problem as well … I’m going to think about this.

Comment: @Konrad: I'm sorry, by your comment I imagined you thought I was using the function name. `:)` It indeed not feasible to use `awk` to get the function escope, that's why I tried the easier path with line ranges. `:)` I also believe in a TeX-only solution, but my TeX-fu is far from acceptable. `:)`

Comment: @Konrad: Sorry, I was unaware of `firstline` and `lastline`! I updated my answer to reflect their use. `:)`

Comment: This is so awesome, I almost cried! ;)

Comment: The third option seems to be broken, sadly.  This seems like a very desirable feature, a shame that it's not available out of the box!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a less invasive, slightly different approach, rebinding `\MintedPygmentize` to a script.  I elected to have parts that one wants to extract explicitly tagged (see example below) using, say, `//!begin:main` and `//!end:main`.

File `extract.sh`:

```
#!/bin/zsh -f

args=($@)
marker=$args[1]
shift args
file=$args[-1]
args[-1]=()

sed -n "\?//!begin:$marker\$? { :a n; \?//!end:$marker\$?q; p; ba }" $file | \
    grep -v '//!' | \
    pygmentize $args
```

File `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\inputmintedannotated}[4][]{
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\MintedPygmentize}{%
    extract.sh\space #2}
  \inputminted[#1]{#3}{#4}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\inputmintedannotated{main}{c}{helloworld.c}

Full file:

\inputminted{c}{helloworld.c}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Why the downvote?  I literally searched again for that question, only to realize that I had provided an answer that I'm still much more likely to use than the one above :/