# importing select lines from external txt file?

Tags: minted, code, import

is there a package that allows one to import a selection of lines from an external .txt file?

I know *minted* has a command that can be customized this way: `\inputminted[firstline=3,lastline=5]{c}{hello.c}` (see this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55324/can-i-print-only-some-functions-with-minted)), but I'm looking for something more neutral, not specific to any programming language. This is because I'm writing a *commands.txt* file with a long list of Cisco's router/switch configuration commands that I'm learning, and I'd like to import only few required lines as a way to showcase examples. Obviously, minted doesn't include any 'cisco' language. I know of `\verb` and the `verbatim` environment,  but I gather there could be problems with breaking long lines.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131894/103046), there is a `text` option for minted that just prints the plain text without highlighting. Does that fulfill your needs?

Comment: Could you please provide a short usage example? I'm not sure what a _lexer_ is, let alone a `text` lexer...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of specifying a proper computer language for syntax highlighting in the environments of the `minted` package, you can use the option `text`. This will just typeset the input verbatim-like without syntax-highlighting but with the full functionality of the `minted` package.

In your case, you probably want to do use `\inputminted` with the `firstline` and `lastline` option. Additionally, just give `text` as first mandatory argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.C}
int main() {
    printf("hello, world");
    return 0;
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\inputminted[firstline=2,lastline=3]{text}{\jobname.C}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it necessary that I use package "filecontents" in the preamble? Or is it just for the sake of the example? I could just go ahead and write `\inputminted[firstline=2,lastline=3]{text}{commands.txt}`, right? (No backslash preceding the file's name, correct?) -- Sorry for the dumb questions!

Comment: That's right. I followed [this guidelines](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/103046) on how to write a Minimal Working Example. `filecontents` is used to have the external file within my LaTeX document, and `\jobname.C` just dynamically assignes the name of the TeX file to the commands file. In your real-world document, you will of course won't need to use `filecontents` and just give the filename as-is.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what's the contents of the file, this might be what you want.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
This is line 1 with \special{characters}
This is line 2 with \special{characters}
This is line 3 with \special{characters}
This is line 4 with \special{characters}
This is line 5 with \special{characters}
This is line 6 with \special{characters}
This is line 7 with \special{characters}
This is line 8 with \special{characters}
This is line 9 with \special{characters}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\verblines}{mmm}
 {
  \begin{flushleft}\ttfamily
  \wobbly_verblines:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  \end{flushleft}
 }

\int_new:N \l__wobbly_verblines_index_int
\ior_new:N \g__wobbly_verblines_file_stream

\cs_new_protected:Nn \wobbly_verblines:nnn
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \g__wobbly_verblines_file_stream { #1 }
  \int_zero:N \l__wobbly_verblines_index_int
  \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g__wobbly_verblines_file_stream
   {
    \int_incr:N \l__wobbly_verblines_index_int
    \int_compare:nT { #2 <= \l__wobbly_verblines_index_int <= #3 } { ##1 \\ }
   }
  \ior_close:N \g__wobbly_verblines_file_stream
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Here are lines 1 to 3
\verblines{\jobname.txt}{1}{3}

Here are lines 2 to 5
\verblines{\jobname.txt}{2}{5}

Here are all the lines
\verblines{\jobname.txt}{0}{100}

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is used just for making the example self-contained. The last example shows what happens if the arguments are beyond the number of lines in the file.

[image]